# Swift MapKit: Calculate ETA for a specific Route and not for directions?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Is there a way to calculate the ETA for a Route and not just for a direction? The problem with the directions is that it only shows one result for the fastest possible route.

Right now i can only find this:

```
   directions.calculateETA { (etaResponse, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error while requesting ETA : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                //travelTime = "Not Available"
            }else{
                print("No error requesting ETA")
                print("\(Int((etaResponse?.expectedTravelTime)!/60)) min")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, `MapKit` has no method for calculating an ETA just for a single route. It wouldn't really make sense anyways to call an ETA for a single `MKRoute`, since you can only get an `MKRoute` instance as the result of an `MKDirections.calculate(completionHandler:)` call, at which point you already have the travel times for the individual routes. The separate `MKDirections.calculateETA` function exists in order to give a quick method for just getting the ETA, since as the [documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkdirections/1452736-calculateeta?changes=latest_minor), this method yields results way faster than the `calculate` function.

You can access the travel time for all `MKRoute`s like this

```
directions.calculate { response, error in
    guard error == nil, let response = response else {return}

    for route in response.routes {
        let eta = route.expectedTravelTime
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that `MKETAResponse.expectedTravelTime` [incorporates traffic conditions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mketaresponse/1452551-expectedtraveltime?changes=latest_minor) into its calculations, while `MKRoute.expectedTravelTime` [uses ideal conditions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkroute/1452297-expectedtraveltime?changes=latest_minor), but at the moment, `MapKit` doesn't have a method for calculating ETA for a single `MKRoute` object with traffic.

Comment: But i thought that calculate ignores Traffic and calculateETA not. Am I wrong on this?

Comment: You are correct, the `expectedTravelTime` property of `MKRoute` reflects travel time in ideal conditions, but there is still no way to calculate an ETA with traffic conditions for a single route. You can only calculate the ETA with traffic conditions for the fastest route. Sadly `MapKit` is still way behind GoogleMaps in quite a few aspects, so if you really need this functionality, you should check out the Google Maps API.

Answer (score 0):

`MKDirections` has a [`calculate(completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkdirections/1452078-calculate) function which returns multiple routes in the `MKDirectionsResponse` object that is returned:

```
directions.calculate { response, error in
    var routes = response?.routes

    let selectedRoute = routes[0]
    let distance = selectedRoute.distance
    let eta = selectedRoute.expectedTravelTime

    // …
}
```

`routes` is an array of [`MKRoute`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkroute) objects which you can then pick out the ones you want.

Comment: Calculating a route takes more than calculating an ETA and OP was asking about ETA...

Comment: @DávidPásztor updated to show how to get the distance and expected travel time from the route

Comment: But i thought that calculate ignores Traffic and calculateETA not. Am I wrong on this?